# firestore rules get() / exists() not working

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am using Firestore rules and want to call `get()`/`exist()` in a function, and after that I call that function in subcollection. But it will give error:

> Error running simulation — An unknown error occurred (viewing outdated simulation)

Can you please help out to point my mistake?

When I try
 allow create: if get(/databases/{database}/documents/Attendants/$(request.auth.uid).data.UserID)!=request.auth.uid

it will give following error:

Error running simulation — Error: simulator.rules line [12], column [31]. Function not found error: Name: [get].; Error: Invalid argument provided to call. Function: [get], Argument: ["||invalid_argument||"] (viewing outdated simulation)

When I follow this document https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions and try exist():

exists(/databases/{database}/documents/admins/$(request.auth.uid));
still not works.

I tried different path in exists and get function even I try full path then it works fine.
`get(/databases/$(database)/documents/GroupExperiences/Experience/PrivateExperience/XmZPoKKQuZBeP68KAIJl/Admins/it07).data`

```
   match /PrivateExperience/{Experience}
   { 
    function isAdmin()
     {
       //return true;
       return exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/Admins/$(request.auth.uid));
          }
          function isAttendant()
          {
            return exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/Attendants/$(request.auth.uid));
          }
        allow create: if request.auth == null; 
         match /Activities/{Activity=**}
        {
         allow create: if (isAdmin() || isAttendant());
        }
       }
```

[image: Rules and testing screen]
[image: Database schema]

Answer (score 4):

Solved Error :

`Error running simulation — An unknown error occurred (viewing outdated simulation)`.
Using `exists(/databases/{database}/documents/Attendants/$(request.auth.uid))`
and this works.

Solved: by trying testing on actual development .

Conclusion: It is issue regarding Firestore rules Simulation.