# Firestore Security rules Get data from another collection

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to write a security rule for firestore which compares the resource.data.EIDSTRING value to a the EIDSTRING value in the app_users collection for the request.auth.uid user. However, I cannot get the rule to evaluate to true, and have found through the bit of debugging firestore rules offers that I am not successfully getting the EIDSTRING field from the app_users collection. I have a similar function that is getting another field from the collection and it works no problem.

Here is the rule file, specifically the problem is with `match/user_contracts/{document}`:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    // Match app_users document
    match /app_users/{userId} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null && belongsTo(userId);
      allow update: if isAdminOrSpecialist(userId) || (request.auth != null 
        && belongsTo(userId)
        && !hasRestrictedFields()
      );
      allow create: if request.auth != null;
      allow delete: if false;
    }

    match /user_contracts/{document} {
      allow read: if hasContract(resource.data.EIDSTRING, request.auth.uid);
      allow write: if false;
    } 

    match /{document=**}{
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
      allow update: if false;
      allow create: if false;
      allow delete: if false;
    }

    function isAdminOrSpecialist(userId){
      let role = get(/databases/$(database)/documents/app_users/$(userId)).data.role;
      return role == 'admin' || role == 'specialist';
    }

    function hasContract(docEID, userId){
      let userEID = get(/databases/$(database)/documents/app_users/$(userId)).data.EIDSTRING;
      return debug(userEID) == debug(docEID);
    }

    function belongsTo(userId){
      return request.auth.uid == userId
    }

    function hasRestrictedFields(){
      return request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).affectedKeys().hasAny(['EIDSTRING','impersonatedGrower', 'role']);
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the test I am running:

```
test.only('Testing read rules for own contracts', async(t) =>{
    const res = await clientReadContracts(fbClient, users.testuser, '26FA348932590C33C3DA6809705ABDFA817712D406A76E62');
    if(res.success){
        t.log(res.message);
        t.pass();
    }else{
        t.log(res.message, res.Error);
        t.fail();
    }
})
```

And the function performing the read:

```
export async function clientReadContracts(
  fbClient,
  client,
  EIDSTRING,
) {
  const clientAdminAuth = clientFirebaseAuth.getAuth();
  const clientAdminUser = await clientFirebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
    clientAdminAuth,
    client.email,
    client.password
  )
    .then(async (userCredential) => {
      return await userCredential.user;
    });
  try {
    const db = clientFirestore.getFirestore(fbClient);
    const collectionRef = clientFirestore.collection(db,'user_contracts');
    
    const query = clientFirestore.query(
      collectionRef,
      clientFirestore.where('EIDSTRING', '==', EIDSTRING)
    );
    
    const querySnapshot = await clientFirestore.getDocs(query);
    if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
      const docSnapshot = querySnapshot.docs[0];
      const docData = docSnapshot.data();
      return { success: true, message: 'doc read', data: docData };
    } else {
      return { success: true, message: 'doc not found', data: '' };
    }
  } catch (err) {
    return { success: false, message: 'failure', Error: err.code };
  }
}
```

As you can see the `isAdminOrSpecialist()` function works really similarly and I have no problem with it, using debug(role) prints out the roles no problem. However, with return `debug(userEID) == debug(docEID)` I only get a printout of the `docEID`, never the `userEID` as if it is undefined or null.

I have visually verified in the emulator that the request.auth.uid matches a document with the correct `EIDSTRING`:

[request.auth.uid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfAla.png)
[resource.data.EIDSTRING](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0oeI.png)
[app_users document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJxIz.png)

There is not much out there on firestore rules so I am hoping somebody here has more experience with this.

I am expecting to get the `EIDSTRING` field from the corresponding `app_users` document for a user, but with debugging it is not printing out. Therefore the rule always evaluates to false.

Comment: Does the rule function properly when the user using `getDoc` to obtain a document that exists that would be returned by the query? (This tests if your security rules are blocking the query or the document read itself)

Comment: I just made some quick edits and tried the `getDoc` method and same behaviour as before, with no debug output for the string acquired using the get path.

Comment: 1) There is a fondamental difference when using `isAdminOrSpecialist` as it retrieves the same document, you could as well use `let role = resource.data.role`

Comment: 2) can you change to `let role = debug(get(/databases/$(database)/documents/app_users/$(userId))).data.role;`

Comment: 1) Thank you for pointing that out, I didn't catch that ```isAdminOrSpecialist``` wasn't implemented as I intended.

Comment: 2) 
I tried setting the rule to use the same GET path as `isAdminOrSpecialist` and it looks like I am still not getting a value. 

```
    function hasContract(docEID, userId){
      let userEID = get(/databases/$(database)/documents/app_users/$(userId)).data.role;
      return debug('userEID' + userEID) == debug('docEID' + docEID);
    }
```
Here is the debug output I get when I run a test that interacts with this rule:
`
string_value: "docEID26FA348932590C33C3DA6809705ABDFA817712D406A76E62"
` 
It only prints out the provided string, not the gotten string.

Comment: I can't understand why I cannot make any edits without getting the 'code not formatted correctly' error. I can't even add text. Im not sure if It's possible to add a multiline code snippet in the comments either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If something changes in the future feel free to answer this question, but for now, I have learned from checking out this 4 year old question: [firestore rules get() / exists() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57376484/firestore-rules-get-exists-not-working?rq=2)
that the emulator STILL does not work perfectly with `get(path)` and `exists(path)`.
I deployed my rule and tested in the playground and it correctly validates a GET request on that rule.

This is a silly oversight as now it makes it impossible for me to test any security in the emulator that interacts with this type of rule validation.

For anyone running across this issue, it may just be simpler to stick with the rules playground in your actual firebase project.